# Загрузка картинок в базу данных

Tags: php, sql

Как взять из формы имя картинки а картинку загрузить в другой файл

```html
$servername = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password = '';
$dbname = 'shop';





$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
   die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

      
      $name = ($_GET['name']);
      $description = ($_GET['description']);
      $price = ($_GET['price']);
      $category = ($_GET['category']);







   
if ($stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO products (name, description, price, category) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)")) {
   
    // Bind the variables to the parameter as strings. 
    $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $name, $description, $price, $category);
 
    // Execute the statement.
    $stmt->execute();
 
    // Close the prepared statement.
    $stmt->close();
    echo "ok";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Данные о загруженных картинках хранятся в массиве $_FILES. http://php.net/manual/ru/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Если поле file имеет имя userfile, то

```
$_FILES['userfile']['name']
```

это оригинальное имя файла.

Для того чтобы сохранить файл на сервер его надо куда-то скопировать из временного файла

```
$_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']
```

Comment: А можно конкретный пример?

Comment: Конечно. Выше я дал ссылку на документацию, там подробно все описано. Вот пример сохранения файла `move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile);`